# What is the correct procedure in GitFlow when merging hotfixes and updating features from one another

Tags: git, git-flow

I have started using GitFlow with my team and it has indeed solved a lot of problems but I have two questions about what the correct procedure is in these cases

a) The development branch uses a different versioning number than the master branch, the master goes like '1.24f.001' '1.25f.001' etc. the development goes like '1.25', '1.26' etc.

When I create a new release I use the development branch, change the version (it is kept in the config files of the project that are saved in Git) and merge into master, and create a tag

But if I make a hotfix for master, its version will go to 1.24f.002 , when I merge that back into development it tries to merge the version number too, which we do not want, other than just not merging the specific file outright is there another way to handle this?

b) Let's say I have started a new feature (A) and another developer has added a new feature (B) after I checked out my feature, but I need some of the fixes from (B) in order to work. What is the correct procedure? manually implement the fixes and when I merge the feature back to development I resolve the conflicts by keeping their changes? or merge development into (A) and move on from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to this, which I've detailed below.

How I currently work with releases and hotfixes is fixing against the release branch, merging the relase branch to `master`, then pulling those hotfixes back into `develop`.

In short, the version is bumped when a release is cut from `develop`. That release is either `major`, `minor` or `patch`. How you manage those release branches is up to you. Bumping the `version` shouldn't happen when merging other branches into the `release` or `develop` branch, because features may end up in`release/1.3.0` and hotfixes may end up `release/1.2.1` OR `develop`, which is pulled back into `release/1.3.0` after being merged into `master.

Two approaches below which should help you with separating both features and hotfixes against `develop`, `master` and `release` branches.

### 1st Approach

Hot fixes that end up within your `release/*` or `master` branch should be pulled back into your `develop` branch, thus, further `release/*` branches will eventually pull these hotfixes. In terms of releasing, ideally, when you take a release branch, this is where you bump the release.

This allows the following:

- Hotfixes branched off `release` or `master` branch can patch release, and pulled back into `develop`
- Features can be branched off `develop` branch can minor release, which will contain hotfixes from `master` branch.

### 2nd Approach

You create a release branch from `develop` which features are merged into. Hotfixes are based off your `develop` branch.

This allows the following:

- Smaller, patch only releases from the `develop` can be released and merged to `master`, then pulled into other `release` branches that contain features.
- Larger `release` branches are contained, and features can easily be designated or "backed out" of a release without polluting the `develop` branch.